# Run 2 different games on 2 cards on 2 monitors in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card

Well i have been looking for 4 hours and i cant find anything. I have a qx6700, 4gbs of ddr2 5 5 5 18 ram, evga 750i FTW mother board, a gts 450, and a gtx 480. What i want to do is set the gpus like i do my cpu core. I want to run 2 vanguard games on each montior, but one using the gtx one using the gts. I have the monitor on the gts, and i put vanguard on the monitor, but some how it is still using the gtx. I think this because on msi afterburner, the gts usage never moves. So i run one on core 0 and 1, and the other on 2 and 3 which gives me a fps increase. Can i run one on one graphics card and one on the other? thank you so much for your time.